# Is there a cyclic dense subgroup of the multiplicative group $Z_p^*$?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, cyclic-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I know that, for $p$ prime, $(Z_p,+)$ is cyclic, in that the subgroup generated by 1 is dense in $(Z_p,+)$. Does there exist $x\in Z_p^*$ such that $\langle x\rangle$ is a dense subgroup?

If so, could we choose $x\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I'm not sure. We can define a power operation in $G=1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$ turning it (the multiplicative group!) into a cyclic (IIRC) $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module. So I would think that the subgroup generated by $1+p$ could be dense in $G$. If $u$ is a primitive root of unity of order $p-1$, then $x=u(1+p)$ might work. I don't remember this piece of theory well enough to be able to answer this with a degree of confidence, so I leave this as a comment. Particularly as I'm not sure whether a rational generator exists. If we were at a bar I would bet a beer in favor of such a rational $x$ existing :-)

Comment: I rephrased the title to pre-empt more misunderstandings.

Comment: That's a good suggestion Jyrki. I'll have a think about this. I might be able to wrangle this to show there are finitely many choices, which is enough for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be odd. Then $(\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic. We can take a generator
to be an integer $a$. Then $a$ also generates the cyclic group
$(\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z)^\times$ for all $k$. Therefore $a$ generates $\Bbb Z_p^\times$.

If $p=2$, then $\Bbb Z_2^\times/(1+8\Bbb Z_2)$ is non-cyclic of order $4$. Therefore
no cyclic subgroup of $\Bbb Z_2^\times$ is dense.